# Django 1.3 URL rewriting

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Django has CommonMiddleware setup, which by default appends a slash to URLs that do not end with one.

For example:
(1) http://www.example.com/admin is rewritten to (2) http://www.example.com/admin/ if it detects in the URLconf that /admin/ exists.

However, I am getting the situation where instead of (2), I am getting (3) http://www.example.com//admin/ which gives me a 404 error.

Is this correct behaviour? What would be one way to resolve the 404 error? 
Thanks a lot.

Note: 
I am running on Django 1.3 + nginx + gunicorn.
I've tried running with Django 1.3 + nginx + apache + mod_wsgi and I'm getting (3) as well (so it's not a webserver problem) but I don't get the 404 error.

======================================================================

## UPDATE:

The problem is with the nginx configuration, which I wrote to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS. 
The following is a sample of the nginx configuration with the error:

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    listen  80; 
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / { 
        rewrite (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
    }   
}

server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/user/certs/example.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/user/certs/example.com.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    location ~ ^/static/(.*)$ {
        alias /home/user/deploy/static/$1;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @django_proxy;
    }

    location @django_proxy {
        proxy_pass          http://django;
        proxy_redirect      off;    
        proxy_set_header    Host                 $host;          
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;   
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol    https;  
    }
}
```

What was happening was the CommonMiddleware was redirecting from https://www.example.com/admin to **http**://www.example.com/admin/. This hit nginx again, and a URL rewrite was done as specified in the config file to https://www.example.com/$1 where $1 is "/admin/". This meant that the final URL was https://www.example.com//admin/.

To correct this, I changed the rewrite rule to:

```
server {
    listen  80; 
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / { 
        rewrite /(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is this correct behavior?" No, it's not. In 4 years of Djangoing I've never seen this particular problem.

One way of testing that the CommonMiddleware is causing this is to comment it out in your `settings.py` file, restart, and then see if you get the same behavior. It can also be instructive to use the standalone development server and stick `print`'s in interesting places to see who is mangling it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I neglected to mention I am running nginx as an SSL reverse proxy. I ran a vanilla instance of Django with the dev server without nginx and the problem does not occur. Looking into it...

Comment: Please report back on what you find. I use nginx on several sites and it's always nice to know of weirdities to look out for.

Comment: It was my error. Thanks for trying to point me in the right direction. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL's.  You most likely have defined your URL's a bit incorrectly.  If you have

```
(r'^admin', include(admin.site.urls))
```

instead of the correct

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

You will see this type of 404 with the middleware

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I've checked this. It is the correct version.