# On clicking link view not loading css and js angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have created a simple angularjs app with component and view
When I include directly component in `index.html` everything works fine but as my app requires multiple view, I am shifting to view but my view when loaded does not get affected by `css` and `js`

This question may seem to be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906506/angular-app-not-loading-css-and-js-on-refreshing-page) but I tried this solution but did not work

[Index.html img link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26028753/38792291-ea56e49a-4169-11e8-88c5-6d32137177de.png)

App.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'myApp.view1',
'myApp.view2',
'sidebar',
'topnavbar',
])
```

view1.module

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1',
['ngRoute',
'knob',
'slider',
'select2',
'rangeslider',
'pickers',
'inputswitcher',
'cropper',
'btscheckbox']);
```

View1.template

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
<div class="row">
    <knob></knob>
    <slider></slider>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <select2></select2>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="row">

        <rangeslider></rangeslider>
    </div>-->
    <div class="row">
        <pickers></pickers>
        <inputswitcher></inputswitcher>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <cropper></cropper>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <btscheckbox></btscheckbox>
    </div>
```

A part of page when component include directly to index:
[link here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26028753/38792443-9bfa3f62-416a-11e8-9996-c553077fcb71.png)

When component loaded from view : [link here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26028753/38792458-abeafb0a-416a-11e8-9186-bb3ec487187b.png)

Comment: are you getting any relevant messages in browser `console`

Comment: No message in log